# Getting apple widgets to refresh frequently - using brute force

Tags: ios, widgetkit

I have tried many combinations of actions to invoke a widget refresh

I have the mail app widget on my home screen and it takes for ever to refresh.

I was hoping to set a shortcut to invoke this. However none exist

I am happy doing this at the smallest interval since my iPad is plugged in all the time

Im sure this can be done. How have others accomplished this

Other solutions are welcome also, but shortcuts the only route i can seem to take ??

Answer (score 3):

WidgetKit widgets are more about displaying information, and less about real-time updates and interaction with the user.

In [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date), Apple says every widget has a refresh quota (“daily budget”).

> The budget allocation is dynamic and takes many factors into account, including:
>
> - The frequency and times the widget is visible to the user.
> - The widget’s last reload time.
> - Whether the widget’s containing app is active.

> For a widget the user frequently views, a daily budget typically includes from 40 to 70 refreshes. This rate roughly translates to widget reloads every 15 to 60 minutes, but it’s common for these intervals to vary due to the many factors involved.

Please note that if the widget is displayed infrequently (e.g. the user had put it in the Today View and have never opened the Today View since), iOS may pause the refresh schedule.

As for your problem, you do have a way to trigger widget refresh at any point. However, doing so will require you to set up push notifications. See, widgets’ owning apps can trigger refreshes, and those refreshes aren’t constrained by the quota.

So basically what you want to do is send push notifications to your app whenever you need to refresh its widget (for example, when there’s a new email in the inbox), and the app will then call [`WidgetCenter`’s](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter) [`reloadTimelines(ofKind:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter/reloadtimelines(ofkind:)) or [`reloadAllTimelines()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter/reloadalltimelines()) method which immediately refreshes the widget.

Comment: Thanks man, I was starting to think that its impossible. Its a shame that I can get this behaviour out of the default mail app

Comment: Good app idea - what do you think haha - will apple do it

Comment: @yakov-manshin did you manage to get it working even with the app killed?